# On clicking text the date picker will open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

I have this text "SetExpiryDate", when i click on this text the date picker will open and after selecting any date the text will become "Expires ${date}"( here date will be the selected one ) and if none of the date will select the text become as it is.

How can i achieve this in ReactJs and also if this will be possible in material UI then it will be good?

How can i achieve this in ReactJs and also if this will be possible in material UI then it will be good?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to achieve it in ReactJS is by using a component collection like MUI.

https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/

Follow the link, you can find the way to install it and the use of each component.